# Excel - IF Value1 or Value 2 in Reference Table, Then N else Y

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to write a formula that outputs either Yes or No depending on if a value is found in a reference table. So:

If A2 is found in range D2:D10 in reference table1, or if B2 is found in range E2:E10 in reference table1, then "No" else "Yes".

So far I have tried different variations of the below without the second OR layer:

```
=IF(G3=INDEX(AB2:AB90,MATCH(G3,AB2:AB90,0)),"N","Y")
```

.

```
=IF(G2=XLOOKUP(G2,$AB$2:$AB$90,$AB$2:$AB$90,"Y"),"N","Y")
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,D2:D10,0)),ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2,E2:E10,0))),"Yes", "No")`

Comment: Thank you @ScottCraner. The ISNUMBER is returning #N/As as the reference table cells the formula should be referring to is also a formula. I've removed the ISNUMBER and some of them are coming through as "No", but the rest are #N/A. Do you have any suggestions for fixing this? This is how I amended your formula: 

=IF(OR(MATCH($A2,$D$2:$D$10,0),MATCH($B2,$E$2:$E$10,0)),"N", "Y")

I also tried the below to get rid of the #N/As:

=IFERROR(OR(MATCH($A2,$D$2:$D$10,0),MATCH($B2,$E$2:$E$10,0)),"Y")

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You don't say anything to indicate that it is important to retrieve the lookup values from the lists they are checked for in. It seems you only need to know they are present. Or not.

Using the lookup to find them would of course give them if found, or an error if not found. So one could do your lookup and use its result, comparing it to the lookup value to get a TRUE, and trap the error, if that happens, in a way to get a FALSE. But none of that is necessary.

You can use the following instead:

```
=IF(  SUM(  (A2 = D1:D20)*1,  (B2 = E1:E20)*1),  "No",  "Yes"  )
```

Each test in the `SUM` compares the appropriate lookup value to the ranges in question and gets an array of TRUE/FALSE values in return. Multiplying each array by "1" coerces that list into arrays of 1/0. Excel can add the values in those arrays via `SUM`, giving you a sum of all the results, and if that sum is anything, any value other than 0, Excel will treat it as TRUE. We think of it from the other direction:  "TRUE = 1" but in truth, Excel regards any non-zero number as TRUE, not just 1. So 43876723 is TRUE, and so on. If neither value is in its lookup list, all the FALSE returns will coerce to being 0's and sum to 0. So now you have either a 1 or a 0 and `IF` can take the appropriate action.